# Statistics notation

Tags: probability, statistics

I came across this notation and am not sure what it means.

$\downarrow$ and $\uparrow$.

For example. Let $A$ be a sample space and we can divide $A$ into $n$ disjoint sets.

$A_N \subset A_{N-1}\dots A_2 \subset A_1$ be an infinite number of subsets such that $A_N \downarrow A$. Then $P(A_N)\to P(A)$ when $n\to\infty$.

What does the down arrow mean? and conversely what does an up arrow mean?

Edit: I misread the question, I have corrected the question above.

Comment: could you post the title and page of the book where you read this?

Comment: Fundamentals of Probability, I misread the question and have corrected it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example the downarrow $\downarrow$ does not seem to make sense to me. Usually it means "*converges monotonically decreasing to*", that is in the case of sets

- $A_N \downarrow A$ means (a) the $A_N$ are decreasing $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots$ **and** (b) $A$ is their intersection $A = \bigcap_N A_N$.

The uparrow analoguously means "*converges monotonically increasing to*" that is

- $A_N \uparrow A$ means (a) the $A_N$ are increasing $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq \cdots$ **and** (b) $A$ is their union $A = \bigcup_N A_N$.

So in your case of increasing sets, you should write $A_N \uparrow A = \bigcup_N A_N$.